# Trouble with 11.10 looking to do a fresh reinstall wondering about losing programs

Tags: installation, software-center, samba, fglrx

So I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit on my new computer that is running Windows 7 as well. I have Ubuntu /root install on sda1 /home on sda2 /swap on sda3 and Win 7 on sda4.

But now my computer is having problems like not being able to install software or the fglrx drivers.

Ubuntu software center tries to fix it, but runs into errors.

I think all the trouble started when I tried to install samba4 and it didn't work.

So here's the question, I have a lot of software installed on my computer like Inkscape, Aptana 3, Netbeans, Gimp, and bunches of school documents. I would like to be able to do a fresh install without losing all those programs.

**Question: Where are programs installed when you install them from the software center??? If it's in /home, perfect I backed it up to a flash drive. If not where???**

If anyone thinks they can help me fix these issues, samba4 not installing, ati fglrx drivers not working, not being able to install software via the software center etc. I'd love to hear your thoughts!

I'm not a complete newbee at Linux but I'm not an expert either - yes I do use bash =)

Thanks for your help!
-Caleb Mellas

Answer (score 1):

No, the programs are not installed in /home - they're usually installed in /usr and they will be removed by the re-install (which totally makes sense in your case since you're having problems with package manager).

Program's user settings, however, are stored somewhere in your home directory, so if you did some configuration it should be preserved if you restore your home directory.

Comment: when I try to uninstall samba4 it gives me an error. Also when I try to use apt-get it gives me an error. when I try sudo apt-get install -f it says:

Comment: Unpacking fglrx-updates (from .../fglrx-updates_2%3a8.881-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb) ...
One or more files have been altered since installation.
Uninstall will not be completed. See /etc/ati/fglrx-uninstall.log for details.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a8.881-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a8.881-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)